# Invoking a function globally within another function

Tags: javascript

I tried this and it seems to work, however I want to know if it is valid code and will be ok with all browsers. I basically want to invoke a function as a global object, only in the case that the user is logged in. It is important that the created object remains in the global scope. So I tried:

```
var specialStuff; // defined globally
```

then some Ajax code within "myMainObject" that calls this.involeSpecialStuff(); if the user is logged-in:

```
myMainObject.prototype.invokeSpecialStuff = function(){
    document.specialStuff = new specialStuff({foo:bar});
});
```

The focus of my question is on the "**document.specialStuff**" part, and if it is the right way to access the globally pre-defined empty "specialStuff" variable, as opposed to "specialStuff = new specialStuff()", which causes "TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new specialStuff({foo:bar});"

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `new specialStuff({foo:bar})` to do? Is `specialStuff` a constructor? Why are you trying to assign the `new` call's return value to the constructor itself?

Comment: It is a set of admin functions that the regular user doesn't need to load.

Comment: Is specialStuff a constuctor? because if it isn't then you shouldn't be using null. If it is a constructor then you should be able to do "specialStuff = new specialStuff()"

Comment: Yes, it is a constructor. But specialStuff = new specialStuff() causes an error: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new specialStuff()

Comment: A global variable called `specialStuff` would be accessed by `window.specialStuff` rather than `document.specialStuff`. Note that in JavaScript *any* function is a constructor if you call it with `new`. But if you're overwriting `specialStuff` with something that is *not* a function then obviously the next time you try to call it it won't work.

Comment: If it's complaining about undefined not being a constructor, then specialStuff isn't a constructor. It's undefined. Given how you've declared it and how you're trying to use it, I don't see why you would think it's a constructor.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried it with window.specialStuff, and this time it gives me "TypeError: Object is not a constructor".

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe I have a problem with the terminology, but I believe it is called a constructor. It is not just one function, but it has properties and other functions are assigned to it, like specialstuff.prototype.doThisAndThat = function () {...}

Comment: Is the error you mention happening the *first* time that code runs, or the *second* and subsequent times? Again, if your `specialStuff = ...` line overwrites `specialStuff` with something that is *not* a function then you *should* get that error the next time. **What does the original `specialStuff()` return** the first time that code runs? (And as I said before, all JS functions are constructors if called with `new`, regardless of whether you've defined additional properties or methods on the associated `prototype`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the explanation you gave and `specialStuff` is a global var which references to a function (class), You cannot do `specialStuff = new specialStuff();` since you are overriding the same value with a new instance from `specialStuff` class. It will work the first time but the next time indeed it is going to trigger the error you mentioned.

You don't need either to use `document.specialStuff` (although it works). You can simple use another variable for it as follows:

```
myMainObject.prototype.invokeSpecialStuff = function(){
    var mySpecialStuff = new specialStuff({foo:bar});
});
```

**EDIT:**

This could be a complete example:

```
// Defining you class in 'global context'
// Since it is called as a constructor below, it should be a function
var specialSuff = function(args){
    // Do your constructor stuff here
};

// Defining a variable which is going to hold an instance of specialStuff
var mySpecialStuff;

myMainObject.prototype.invokeSpecialStuff = function(){
    // Creating an instance of specialStuff 
    mySpecialStuff = new specialStuff({foo:bar});
});
```

Comment: But then mySpecialStuff will only exist in the scope of myMainObject, won't it?

Comment: `var` will make it a local variable in the containing function, so `mySpecialStuff` will exist only in the scope of the current invocation of the `invokeSpecialStuff` function.

Comment: Yes, but you can make it global as 'specialStuff'

Comment: Made an edit to the answer to provide a complete example

Comment: Your edited version worked for me. Thanks! :) So was the error only a problem of the instance having the same name as the class itself?

Comment: I think the problem was that your class was not a function but 'undefined' and then other problem (in case you needed another class-instance) was that you were overriding the class with a class-instance

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the document part in order to store a global variable in javascript. Probable better to just do

```
specialStuff = new specialStuff({foo:bar});
```

Of course, I always will question whether you really need this global function. Globals are always something to avoid in most cases.

Comment: I tried that first, but as said, it causes an error: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new ...